# Can anyone identify the red leaf in my photo?

Tags: identification, leaf

I'm an artist working with ecological themes. So I like to know what I'm painting or drawing about:) Took this picture to use as a model of ginko leaves;  Have searched using images and listed several sites advertising red leaved plants found no match.
I'd appreciate any ideas you all might have.[image]

Comment: Where in the world are you located? In what month of the year did you take the photo? Do you have other photos that show more of the red-leaved plant, especially something from farther away?

Comment: Any idea why the the ginkgo leaves are so pale?

Comment: The Gingko leaves are 'pale' -yellow actually- which means its mid to late autumn when this picture  was taken,that's  what gingko leaves look like when they fall. The red leaf may not be from a red-leaved plant, it may just be red because its autumn and it turns that oolour before  it falls. We need to see more of the red leaf for  ID purposes

Answer (score 1):

The leaf is red becasue it's fallen, not because it grew as a red leaf.

My gut reaction is that it looks like "Burning Bush" *Euonymus alatus* - but could be something else. Those are green until fall, and the distinctly pink coloration and toothed edges match up.

[image: Burning Bush leaves in fall]

Image from: https://www.maine.gov/dacf/mnap/features/invasive_plants/euonymus.htm

Comment: Color is right, but the leaf shape is wrong. Some dogwoods produce the same color autumn leaves, but the venation is clearly wrong here for that to be correct. The leaf in the photo also appears ruffled, although that could easily be specific to just that leaf. I don't think there's enough detail in the photo for us to ID the leaf.